# Regex match cannot get to work

Tags: regex

I've spent far to long trying to get this to work. I'm trying to validation only for the following:
alpha numerics, hyphens, full stops, exclamation marks, open/closing brackets (normal not curly), forward slashes and question marks.

I thought it was the following regex

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9\!\(\)\-\/\.\?\s])+/
```

Which kinda works as if I put #~ in the box, it shows that it is invalid. However if I put #~Paul then it states that the match is valid true. It seems to say true as soon as it finds a valid character. The example #~Paul should be false as it contains invalid characters. Should only be true if all characters are valid ones.

Example of working matches should be.
Paul!!
Paul (Stack-Overflow.)!

I'm sure some whizz can help me out there. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\!\(\)\-\/\.\?\s])+$
```

What you need are anchors to make validation strict.

Comment: Thank you! Was just about to post I found the answer, however my answer was going to be the following. What would be the difference between mine and your? /^[a-zA-Z0-9\!\(\)\-\/\.\?\s]*$/

Comment: You can reduce the escaped chars in the class; `[-A-Za-z0-9!.()\/?\s]`

Comment: @Cann0nF0dder `*` means 0 or more,`+` means 1 or more.For your case `+` is better